# watir webdriver print the count of a list item

Tags: ruby, rspec, webdriver, watir

I'm trying to get the count of a list item in a web page and outputting this:

```
office_lists = browser_driver.li(:class, 'office')
office_list = browser_driver.li(:class, 'office')

office_list = Hash.new 0
office_list.links.each do |link|
  office_list[link] += 1
  puts office_list
```

But I have been unsuccessful. I was hoping someone could. Say these are all my li on the page

```
<li class=‘office’></li>
<li class=‘office’></li>
<li class=‘office’></li>
<li class=‘office’></li>
<li class=‘office’></li>
<li class=‘office’></li>
```

i would then like to put this in some sort of an array object, then get the count and the output the number of items like so:

```
puts "There are #{count} number of offices in the list"
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
also do i need to require anything such as "pp" or "p" or anything else or will watir be enough for this task?

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding what you have declared first

For an example,

```
office_lists = browser_driver.li(:class, 'office')
office_list = browser_driver.li(:class, 'office')

office_list = Hash.new 0
```

You are replacing office_list by Hash so your `browser_driver.li(:class, 'office')` will no longer available in office_list.

And I don't understand whether you want to count the links under a particular list or you want to count total number of lists.

If you want to count links under a particular list, then write the below code

```
p browser.li(:class, 'office').links.count
```

The above line will print the number of links under that list

If you want to count total numbers of lists, then write the following code

```
count= browser.lis(:class, 'office').count #its `lis` not `li`
puts "There are #{count} number of offices in the list"
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rolling your own method, you can use the built-in [`lis`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir/Watir/Container#lis-instance_method) method, which returns a collection of `li` elements.

Here's an example the collects the `li` elements with a class attribute of "office" and then chains `Array::count` to return the number of elements in the collection:

HTML (in a local file named `foo.rb`):

```
<li class='office'></li>
<li class='office'></li>
<li class='office'></li>
<li class='office'></li>
<li class='office'></li>
<li class='office'></li>
```

watir snippet:

```
require 'watir'

b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
b.goto "file:///C:/foo.html"
count = b.lis(class: 'office').count
puts count
#=> 6
puts "There are #{count} number of offices in the list"
#=> There are 6 number of offices in the list
```